# Custom page but not want to display in pages section in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a php page for a dictionary game. In the beginning, I don't want to display my custom page in pages sectionof my website, but **I want to reach it by a URL**.

How can I do it ?

*(Note: I had setted its status password secured and private before. But It's not the solution what I need.)*

Comment: why you don't use wordpress `template` http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates  or tell me you want to use a dictionary page in out of wordpress project of or under wordpress project?

Comment: Under wordpress project. I used it, but page title is shown in pages section of my website. Only I want to hide my template page from the pages section in header of te page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There a few steps...

1. Create a page in Editor and titled it 'Dictionary game'or what you want.
2. Create php template in your theme folder  `mydictionary.php`
3. Add [Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates) name in first line of `mydictionary.php`
4. Add [theme support](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support) in your theme `functions.php` file, you will see right side Page Attributes box, you can assign template in a page.

**FOR DON'T SHOW ON WEBSITE SECTION**

1. If you won't show that page on site section then you use [WP Nav Manu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) its fully editable or if you call `wp_list_pages` to show pages list then pass a parameter in function like  `wp_list_pages('exclude=PAGEID')`.

for multi attributes `wp_list_pages('&exclude=PAGEID')`

**FOR URL**

1. Wordpress give url like 'mysite.com/?p=10' if you want a seo friendly url like  'mysite.com/dictionary-game' then you need to make seo friendly url in left side Settings > Permalink select `post name` option and update.

**FOR MAKE DEFAULT DICTIONARY-PAGE**   mean when user open your its bring on `Dictionary-Game` page.

1. Go to Settings > reading   select option named `static page (select below)` and on options `Front page:` select your page that you created on page named  `Dictionary game` and make save changes

Comment: I do not want to do a static reading page. I want to hide my page link from pages section into the header of my website. I do not want any people to see my custom page url.

Comment: what you use function to show links in header section where you don't want to show your dictionary page?

Comment: <?php if($theme->display('menu_primary')) { $theme->hook('menu_primary'); } ?>   but I do not know how to reach menu_primary query for editing.

Comment: i've already told in my answer use `wp_nav_menu` its fully manageable from admin panel

Comment: hey why you have vote down my answer is there i provide any fake instruction, in my answer i don't force to make a static reading page its depends on you if you don't make it static page then leave that step...

Comment: I will vote it up after 32 mins. FOR DON'T SHOW ON WEBSITE SECTION part is enough ;)